# localStorage not set after this.props.history update

Tags: reactjs, react-router, local-storage

I think I am fundamentally misunderstanding how BrowserRouter works in React.

I am trying to use local storage to store an OAuth token after authorization is successful. The user is supposed to be redirected to the login page on load if there's no such entry in local storage (which is working as intended), but upon initial login (through Google Sign-In, in this case), it redirects back to the login page again instead of bringing me through to the requested page. If I refresh at this stage, or enter the URL I'm trying to visit, I'm taken to the correct page.

My base component is as follows:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userToken: window.localStorage.getItem('userToken')
        }
    }

    loginRedirect() {
        if(!this.state.userToken) return <Redirect to='/login'/>
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                { this.loginRedirect() }
                <Route exact path='/' component={Main}/>
                <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

I use PassportJS with the Google OAuth2 strategy for authorization, and I send the token to the client by redirecting to the login URL with the token as a query parameter:

```
router.get('/callback', Passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }), (req, res) => {
    const token = req.user.token;
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/login?token=' + token);
});
```

Which is parsed inside the Login component, which then sets the localStorage and redirects back to the root page:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const query = QueryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    if(query.token) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('userToken', query.token);
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }
}
```

At this point, my base component's constructor fires, but the 'userToken' value in localStorage is not set, and so the state doesn't get set, and the login redirect fires again.

Any explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What I can see is you're trying to redirect user to `http://localhost:3000/login?token=xxx` which triggers the token saving procedure. 

But it got intercepted by `this.loginRedirect()` and by that time `this.state.userToken` is still empty.

Then it got redirected to `<Redirect to='/login'/>` without any parameters.

Comment: Thanks, HaoWu. I think that the query param still gets preserved though, as I can immediately query localStorage for the token after getting redirected back to login after auth.

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried to clear the local storage before testing? If not it might caused by the existing data saved in storage before. Else it's probably because there's no where else is setting the `userToken` in the `state` of the `App`. Which the `constructor` of the `App` only runs once if you didn't hard refresh the page.

Comment: Yes, I clear local storage each time to simulate a logout. Each time I refresh after doing so, I am brought back to the login page, which is the expected behavior.

The constructor runs first upon each redirect.

Comment: In that case, try to replace `this.props.history.push('/')` with `window.location.href = '/'`

Comment: That works, thank you! Any idea what that's the case? I think I'm missing something regarding the component lifecycle or the way the BrowserRouter works.

Comment: Basically you need a hard refresh after the token has been saved like most other websites, to reconstruct the whole app based on that token. (In this particular case, to run the `constructor` of `App` again, because router won't refresh the whole App)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set new token to state.

```
setUserToken = (token) => {
  this.setState({ userToken: token })
}
```

and send to `Login` component

```
<Route path='/login' render={() => <Login setUserToken={this.setUserToken} />}/>
```

And set userToken from `Login` component

```
if(query.token) {
   window.localStorage.setItem('userToken', query.token);
   this.props.setUserToken(query.token)
   this.props.history.push('/');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Especially for making me aware of the "render" prop in Router. It still wasn't working, but I made a few modifications:

`componentWillMount() {
    const query = QueryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    if(query.token) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('userToken', query.token);
        this.props.onSuccess(query.token);
    }
}`

and

`handleSuccess(token) {
    this.setState({
        userToken: token
    }, () => {
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }); 
}
`
As well as wrapping <App/> (withRouter-ed) in a BrowserRouter.